# Does MongoDB insert data with its metadata?

Tags: mongodb, memory-management

When a DB is created in MongoDB with some sample data, will it store the Meta data in RAM?

Whenever I try to create a Database my memory, the memory usage is increased.
How does MongoDB use its RAM for storing data in the DB?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. All database will use RAM, and will increase its RAM usage as more data is inserted or queried. This is not special to MongoDB. If you're having a specific issue, please post any error message you see.

Comment: There is no any issue when i create a database. But while creating a database the RAM is increased.